# When SSHed into Ubuntu Core how to know which container running from

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core, container

I setup a Ubuntu Core 22 IoT device and I was able to SSH into it.

Since Ubuntu Core is a container operating system ,I wanted to know if I am SSHed into the device which container is my  SSH session running out of?

Since Ubuntu Core uses  LXD & LXC I thought there might be a command to run to determine this.  However, when I run the lxc command I get the following:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ lxc list
-bash: lxc: command not found
```

Here is my qestions:

- Which container is my SSH session running out of?
- If Ubuntu Core uses LXD/LXC why isn't this lxc command installed by default
- Is there a way to view all the containers?
- If I view the snaps is this the same as viewing containers?

Comment: The assumption that Ubuntu Core includes LXD is incorrect. LXD does work great on Ubuntu Core *after* LXD is installed. The assumption that snap packages are containers is also incorrect. Snaps are sandboxed, but generally not by using containers.

Comment: Hmm... why doesn't LXD work well on Ubuntu Core after it is installed?  Does Docker work better?

Comment: Your output suggests that you have not installed LXD onto your Ubuntu Core system yet. When you do, you will discover that it works very well.